# Jquery validator plugin is not validating using complex names

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following content of a form.

```
<form id="edit-form" action="" method="post">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2">
        <label for="id_first_name">First Name:<span class="help-inline">  *</span></label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_customer-first_name" maxlength="150" name="customer-first_name" type="text" value="Neville">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2">
        <label for="id_middle_name">Middle Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_customer-middle_name" maxlength="150" name="customer-middle_name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2">
        <label for="id_last_name">Last Name:<span class="help-inline">  *</span></label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_customer-last_name" maxlength="200" name="customer-last_name" type="text" value="Sarginson">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2">
        <label for="id_telephone">Telephone:<span class="help-inline">  *</span></label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_customer-telephone" maxlength="25" name="customer-telephone" placeholder="(XXX) XXX-XXXX" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2">
        <label for="id_mobile">Mobile No:</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_customer-mobile" maxlength="25" name="customer-mobile" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2">
        <label for="id_work_phone">Work Phone No:</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" id="id_customer-work_phone" maxlength="25" name="customer-work_phone" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I use jquery validation plugin to validate the inputs of the form in the following way.

```
$('#edit-form').validate({
            /* @validation states + elements
                ------------------------------------------- */

                errorClass: "state-error",
                validClass: "state-success",
                errorElement: "em",

                /* @validation rules
                ------------------------------------------ */

                rules: {
                        "customer-first_name": {
                                required: true
                        },
                        "customer-last_name": {
                                required: true
                        },
                        "customer-email": {
                                required: true,
                                email: true
                        },
                        "customer-telephone": {
                                required: true
                        }
                },

                /* @validation error messages
                ---------------------------------------------- */

                messages:{
                        "customer-first_name": {
                                required: 'Enter first name'
                        },
                        "customer-last_name": {
                                required: 'Enter last name'
                        },
                        "customer-email": {
                                required: 'Enter email address',
                                email: 'Enter a VALID email address'
                        },
                        "customer-telephone": {
                                required: 'Enter patient\'s telephone number'

                        }
                },

                /* @validation highlighting + error placement
                ---------------------------------------------------- */

                highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                        $(element).closest('.field').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
                },
                unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                        $(element).closest('.field').removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                   if (element.is(":radio") || element.is(":checkbox")) {
                            element.closest('.option-group').after(error);
                   } else {
                            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                   }
                }


        });
```

The proper js library is included but still it won't validate. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In the documentation it says in the guidelines that I can use complex names by quoting them

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your JavaScript console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, correct, you must surround complex names with quotes.

However, your code, as you've presented it to us, is working:  http://jsfiddle.net/7pmc6q9c/

```
....
    rules: {
        "customer-first_name": {
            required: true
        },
        "customer-last_name": {
            required: true
        },
        "customer-email": {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        "customer-telephone": {
            required: true
        }
    },
....
```

- Your `customer-first_name` and `customer-last_name` fields already have values set in the HTML so there is nothing to validate unless the user blanks them out.
- Your `customer-email` field does not exist in the HTML so validation ignores it.
- Your `customer-telephone` field is being validated exactly as you've specified.

Comment: Yes the problem was that I used the code template from an admin template, so It used some classes that didn't exist. I switched to formValidator for bootstrap. It works great!